# Updating same table multiple with in a transaction

Tags: sql-server

Can we write multiple quires in a single sql transaction referring same table. What are the pros and cons of it.

```
                BEGIN TRANSACTION

                UPDATE TRANSACTION_LINEITEM
                SET TRN_STAT_ANID = @3
                WHERE TRN_ANID = @1;

                UPDATE TRANSACTION_LINEITEM
                SET TRN_TNDR_TYP_ANID = @6
                WHERE TRN_ANID = @1 AND TRN_TNDR_TYP_ANID = 3;

                COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Yes, you can do multiple writes to the same table. Pros and cons don't really enter into it; you use transactions based on your application's requirements.

Comment: Well, the pros are that you get an atomic unit of work. The cons are that you lock database resources until the transaction is committed or rolled back. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: I have some dead lock logs, The table TRANSACTION_LINEITEM is becoming the victim, This table is used in this transaction and also in a select query in another procedure. I can share the deadlock log file, But it is too long, i can provide the information, Please help me with your questions, so that i can provide the required information.

Comment: You could easily do this in a single update statement. Please tell me your real variable names are better than just numbers.